# JSON data as table in Drupal

Tags: json, rest, drupal-7

I am a Drupal 7 newbie and I am hoping someone can help me.

I have a REST API on another server and there is method there which return JSON data, the data is the same for all Drupal users.

My question is that how could I display this data in Drupal? I need a page and on that I would like this JSON rendered as a HTML table.

Any feedback would be most appreciated.

Comment: This is too broad of a question and has not shown any effort to actually research and solve the problem.

Comment: disagree! would not care if i had not researched. i tried configuring the rest client and end points and custom content types but not luck

Comment: Then show you code attempts so far. Explain what specifically is not working.

Comment: i dont have code to show because i am trying to use drupal modules such as REST Client and Views and Content Types but that doesn't seem to work since i am unable to comprehend how the UI should be connected.

Answer (score 1):

There is no module AFAIK that will just automatically pull data from any arbitrary API and theme it nicely. You are going to need to make a custom module.

To do what you are saying could probably be done in as few as 15 lines of code, but you will need to learn how to create a module first.

Check out: https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360

Once you have created your module, you will need a hook_menu() function to create the page to display the json results.

In the callback function for that page you will need to call your API and then you can theme the results into a table by using theme('table', array('rows' => $rows, 'header' => $header));

There is a decent tutorial here:
http://alvinalexander.com/drupal/drupal-7-form-theme-table-module-example

Assuming you have some experience programming with PHP then expect to spend 3-4 hours on this (based on learning curve and reading involved).

Comment: I've the same question to get JSON rendered as a HTML table in drupal. Would be much help if you show the code of the module on how to display the results.